# opening luigi.LocalTarget in binary read mode (decoding error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, luigi

I'm trying to open a luigi.LocalTarget for reading that points to a zip file (so that I can calculate a hash).  Unfortunately, when I try to read it, I get a UnicodeDecodeError, which I assume means its not getting opened as a binary file.

I can do this (without luigi) and it works fine

```
file_path  = luigi.LocalTarget('myfile.zip')
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read(1048576)
```

But if I do this

```
target = luigi.LocalTarget(file_path)
with target.open('rb') as f:
    data = f.read(1048576)
```

I get this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-5240759ed677> in <module>()
      1 target = luigi.LocalTarget(file_path)
      2 with target.open('rb') as f:
----> 3     data = f.read(1048576)

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and luigi 2.6.1.  Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Luigi is stripping 'b' and 't' in it's open method, not sure why:

http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/luigi/local_target.html#LocalTarget.open

```
def open(self, mode='r'):
        rwmode = mode.replace('b', '').replace('t', '')
```